# How can I place Button or TextView at the absolute bottom in RelativLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

There seems to be some hidden padding in the RelativLayout, I'm I right?

I've got this TextView:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:text="LOG IN"/>
```

in a RelativeLayout.

What I cant understand is why

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

doesn't place the TextView all the way down. 
ref image:

[image]

Is there any way to remove this padding?

Comment: Try to check `dimens.xml` under `res/values` folder

Comment: Very nice. Cant believe I couldn't find that answer anywhere

Comment: Yeah I had the same issue... Android studio auto generates it.. I think you could have figured it out by checking your layout xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question was very easy and provided by @Marco Dufal.

Go in the dimens.xml in the res/values folder and set the margin to 0dp:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the TextView's parent is the Entire RelativeLayout.

TextView is indeed at RelativeLayout's Bottom, but doesn't mean that RelativeLayout's bottom is aligned with the screen's absolute bottom.

Try set android:layout_marginBottom = "0px"  for your RelativeLayout.

BTW, padding is used between Layout and its Views inside, margin is used outside between Layout and screen borders

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and do let me know if you find any problem ... thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="2dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_text_back"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```